# SELECT vs CREATE TABLE AS SELECT execution time

Tags: postgresql

My function should return a `TABLE` which is created by lots of joins and is relatively "big".

If inside of my function i put `return query select <complex query goes here>;` then it takes ages (more like 10-15 mins) to run.

However, if instead of returning a `TABLE`, I return `VOID` and simply create a table within function body - it finished under 1 min.

The same goes for running this "complex query" as `select <complex query goes here>` VS `create table <table name> as select <complex query goes here>` and then `select * from <table_name>`.

Why is there such a difference in execution time?

P.S. The select clause of the query has around 35 columns with some logic inside.

P.P.S. The query returns only about 90K rows, so I doubt that it is the time that takes to send the data over the network

Comment: time to retrieve data?.. compare plans - they should be same for both, if so the time it takes is sending data to the client (and displaying it)

Comment: To verify that, try to `SELECT *` from the table created in the fast version.

Comment: SELECT * from that table takes about 10 secs to return the data

Comment: @Dennis ALL the data?.. or just a page?.. Laurenz way is good, but can be overcame by client - try running `\copy table_name to 'local_file'` in `psql`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Ok. Don't know why it happens, but select * for "all the data" takes very long as well (i stopped it after some minutes). The "copy" command accomplishes the same in 3 secs. Any idea why that might be? The size of the output text file is 36MB.

Comment: SQL `copy` and psql meta command `\copy` are extremely different in this approach - di you run copy in 3 secs or `\copy`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Sorry for omitting the important details. I ran \copy

Comment: so then the issue is not transferring data, but displaying it to you :) which client you have?..

Comment: @VaoTsun PgAdmin. And I hate (almost) every second of using it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**answer**

`select` differs from `create table as select` in manner where you use the data, first will send data to the client and the latter will save it to disk server side.

**why**

Possible reasons could be slow link, and "feature" of the client. According to the fact that local `psql` running `\copy (select * from) to 'local_file'` took 3 seconds and yet PgAdmin took ages to display sam data, I assume you version PgAdmin (or any version at all) is not meant for your amount of data to display (as you say 36MB). So it was not the link, but the client.

Comment: PSequel takes 40secs to display all the data

Comment: SQLWorkbenchJ takes 1min